# cakephp how to create data validation for hasMany model?

Tags: cakephp-2.1

My user hasMany address. I wish to collect all the address from same view file.
So i named the fields as [model][0][field_name], [model][1][field_name] .... , [model][n][field_name].
I use saveMany function to add all the data at once.

The validation code i created in model works for only [model][0] fields alone.

How to make the data validation for all the set of fields?